# EJS recieve json containing code as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, ejs

Im sending a stringified json that should have property:

```
recievedObject: {"code":"this is a code snippet"}
```

(the `code` property has no specified programming language)

and then parsing it like this:

```
var items = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(items) %>')
```

When I try to parse the stringified json I received I get parsing errors (im guessing its because of the `code` string often containing characters like " ', line breaks etc.)

Is there a way to bypass or get around this problem without changing the string in any way? (I was able to get this working after encrypting it, but I would prefer not to do this)

example of how the `code` string might look:

```
code: "router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {\n" +
'  try {\n' +
'    const cities = spreadsheet.getData()\n' +
'\n' +
'  } catch(err) {\n' +
'    console.log(err)\n' +
'  }\n' +
'\n' +
"  res.render('index', { cities: cities})\n" +
'})'
```

Comment: Just `var items = <%- JSON.stringify(items) %>`, since JSON is [almost always](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) valid JavaScript code.

Comment: @Amadan Ive tried what you suggested, however now im getting a "missing ) after argument list" error and Im  starting to think that there is something wrong with the code string itself, can you take a look at it? for  easier readability Ill edit it into the question

Comment: That should not be happening. Can you show the relevant portion of the rendered template? I.e. not how original data is, but what EJS generated? Also, you said you tried it but I don't see code for it so I can't begin to guess what is wrong.